# How should WSDL be structured?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap, wsdl

As I am new to WSDL, WCF and SOAP, I have no real clue how I should structure the WSDL.

My problem right now is that when a user logs in using their username//password, the server should respond with data owned by the user. Lets say the data that wants to be sent back are:

- MatterID
- MatterTitle
- MatterText
- MatterDate

The problem is that each user can own more than 1 matter and my problem is that I have no idea how to parse more than the first *Matter* that the server send as response. My WSDL is structured something like this:

IN:

- username
- password

OUT:

- int MatterID
- str MatterTitle
- str MatterText
- int MatterDate

Am I doing it wrong? Should I respond with a list instead containing all the data? Or is there a way to loop through a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of data to return, you better define a list in the WSDL (the types section) like so:

```
 <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://localhost/SampleService" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

        <s:complexType name="MatterItemType"> <!-- List Item -->
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="MatterID" type="s:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <s:element name="MatterTitle" type="s:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> 
                <s:element name="MatterText" type="s:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <s:element name="MatterDate" type="s:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>                      
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>

        <s:complexType name="MatterListType"> <!-- List -->
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="MatterItem" type="tns:MatterItemType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>

        <!-- Request and Response -->

        <s:element name="SampleRequest">
                <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>           
                    <s:element name="username" type="s:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <s:element name="password" type="s:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>                                
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>

        <s:element name="SampleResponse">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>                    
                    <s:element name="MatterList" type="tns:MatterListType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>            
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>    

    </s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

The Response always contains a **MatterList** element which is of **MatterListType**. The **MatterListType** contains from 0 to N **MatterItem** items defined in the **MatterItemType**.

The response will be structured something like this (not including SOAP envelope, namespaces, etc, just for illustration of the structure):

```
<SampleResponse>
    <MatterList>
        <MatterItem>
            <MatterID>1</MatterID>
            <MatterTitle>Title1</MatterTitle>
            <MatterText>Text1</MatterText>
            <MatterDate>1</MatterDate>
        </MatterItem>
        <MatterItem>
            <MatterID>2</MatterID>
            <MatterTitle>Title2</MatterTitle>
            <MatterText>Text2</MatterText>
            <MatterDate>2</MatterDate>
        </MatterItem>
    </MatterList>
</SampleResponse>
```

Let me know if you need more help in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I am writing the WSDL in a whole different environment "business system called Pyramid", I'll see if I can construct similar thing in that language.

Comment: Glad I helped! WSDL is a standard, so you should be able to do this if really is WSDL.

Comment: I don't really get how I should be able to parse the list. Here is my attempt: https://gist.github.com/jakobmillah/122bf8e6726113dafd87

ActivityRow is the a class generated by the Service Reference. It contains all the data, like: private string MatterID; private string MatterTitle;

GetUserActivity 2 parameters, username//password and should respond with the list, but I am doing something wrong. I tried with a google plugin to use that username and password and I get a valid response.

Comment: I should not parse the respond directly to an ActivityRow class. That's what I think I am doing wrong, but I don't know how I should do it.

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to comprehend this from a distance, but I think you should be using a collection/array of ActivityRow items - see if there is one in the reference. If GetUserActivity only returns ActivityRow, then maybe it only returns the last one. See if you can find some other method like GetAllUserActivity that returns them all at once in a collection. You could also try to parse the raw response directly from the response text. Also, check for version of GetUserActivity with "out parameters" - maybe your full response is there.

Comment: Ye understandable that it's hard to help out when its hard to provide all necessary information. I have no clue if the WSDL is 100% correctly made, since the documentation how to do respond with a list is really badly made. - GetUserActivity returns "ArrayOfActivityRows", object of ActivityRow. - This is how the code is written in "Pyramid" - https://gist.github.com/jakobmillah/6c0afe5ef74ee000c0d3 - It's kind of speaking for itself. I can't find a method similar to something like "GetAllUserActivity".

Comment: It looks like the sample I posted. If nothing else works try getting the raw xml response and parse it.

Comment: I'll check it out. They got methods regarding XML, one Qeury and one Response.. But again, documentation is so insanely bad that I simply can't figure out what they are meant for :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jakobmillah/d434d4f4d43f3f2faadf This is what I've done so far. I figured out that the response is an array and not a list, which is a bit sad, but yeye. My problem is that I do not get anything parsed. The array does not contain anything after the response sequence. I added all code to that github. - client - c# contains the request. - generated-activity-class & generated-req-resp is code generated by the reference. - soap-response is the response I get when using the same username // password directly in the browser. Feel free to take a look at it!

Comment: Could something like making a Service Reference instead of Web Reference cause the issue? I have managed to get response using Service Reference, but that was before I changed to an array as response.

Comment: I solved my problem. The reason why I didn't get anything was because of failing structure of the WSDL. Same thing has happened before, but not really in the same structure way. I find it hard to locate these types of errors within WSDL. Is there a nice way to debug them? For future projects :) Thanks for your input though, @PlamenPetrov

Comment: It's holidays here, so I'm sorry I could not help you further - it has been busy! Anyway, congrats you have solved it! The tool I use in such cases is Eclipse. It has a good validation tool within. When you open a WSDL, look for Validate in the contect menu when you click in the text. It will find most structural problems. Use SOAP UI for testing of the service itself.