# Can a SOAP operation have multiple outputs?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

Is it possible for a SOAP operation, which defined in a WSDL file, to have multiple outputs?

Example:

```
<operation name="getUserInfo">
    <input message="getUserIdRequest"/>
    <output message="getUserNameResponse"/>
    <output message="getUserEmailResponse"/>
</operation>
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, the answer should be no because a method only return one element. If so, what can I do to get multiple data using only one operation?

Comment: No you can not have 2 output values. You can construct a output value, wich contains multiple values

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

`<message name="getTermResponse">
  <part name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  <part name="email" type="xs:string"/>
</message>`



`<operation name="getUserInfo">
  <input message="getUserInfoRequest"/>
  <output message="getUserInfoResponse"/>
 </operation>`

Comment: Yes something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is done with arrays. You can use a complex types and the `maxOccurs` attribute set to `unbounded` in order to create an array of a type of items in the response.

Here is a sample for such a type:

```
    <s:complexType name="MatterListType"> <!-- List -->
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element name="MatterItem" type="tns:MatterItemType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
```

Check out [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29533449/510615) from some time ago, where I explain how it is done in more detail.

If you just need multiple different output fields and not arrays, define the response itself as a complex type (you can see this in the above example as well).

I hope this helps, let me know if I can help you further! Good luck.

Comment: Actually, your other answer is what is really going to help me :)

Comment: It doesn't matter, the important thing is you found out what you want! Glad to be of help :)